Problem with UPGRADE 24.04
UBUNTU STUDIO 24.04 told me: No se ha podido eliminar el paquete del sistema:
WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages:
libapt-pkg6.0 (due to apt)
libgnutls30 (due to apt)
libext2fs2 (due to e2fsprogs)
What can/must I do?
Thanks for HELP me
J

libapt-pkg6.0 is not in Ubuntu Studio 24.04. It was removed after 22.04. Did your release upgrade complete properly with zero errors? Or did the system offer you a "partial upgrade?" Please open a terminal and run both sudo apt update and of sudo apt upgrade. Copy and paste the complete output of both into your question above.
